# Prove $k\binom nk=n \binom{k-1}{ n-1}$ algebraically.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I need to prove $k\binom nk=n \binom{k-1}{ n-1}$ where $n$ and $k$ are integers with $1\leq k\leq n$ using an algebraic proof.

I solved the left side which is $\binom nk$ using the pascals identity for $\binom nr$. But,now when i am trying do the same for the right side, i cant solve it. Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: I've edited to bring out the intended (I hope) meaning, but note that the second binomial coefficient looks upside-down; as it stands, this is certainly not true.

Answer (score 2):

For $\displaystyle n\geq k>0$ and $n, k\in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot k!}=n\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{k\cdot (k-1)![(n-1)-(k-1)]!}=\frac nk\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: For $n=k$ we have $(n-k)!=0!=1$ and it has meaning.

Comment: @impartialmale, I would request for pinpointing the errors.Thanks

Comment: Please read the content of the question. They need the equality for all $k, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0< k\leq n$ not only $0<k<n$.

Answer (score 0):

The usual definition of binomial coefficients $\binom nk$, with only the condition $k\in\mathbf N$, is
$$
  \binom nk=\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!} =\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k\times (k-1)\times\cdots\times 1}
$$
Splitting off the initial factors of numerator and denominator for $k>0$ gives the identity
$$
  \binom nk=\frac nk\binom{n-1}{k-1} \qquad\text{for $k>0$.}
$$
This gives after multiplying by $k$ your (presumably) desired identity $k\binom nk=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. This is therefore valid under the sole hypothesis that $k$ is a positive integer. If one extends the above definition by setting  $\binom nk=0$ whenever $k$ is a negative integer (again this is conventional), then it even holds for all $k\in\mathbf Z$.